# UIBarButtonItem is too wide

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a `UIBarButtonItem` to my `UINavigationController`.

The button is too wide though and the hit area seems to stretch beyond the bounds of the image.

[image]

In my `viewDidLoad` I am simply applying:

```swift
let leftNavButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hamburger_icon"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavButton
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change size of UIBarButtonItem (image) in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073738/change-size-of-uibarbuttonitem-image-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 1):

There can be a problem with an image size of `hamburger_icon`, try to use a random system icon to see if the image is still too wide.