# navigation bar button item is bigger than the frame i set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I don't know what's wrong with my code or what did I did that leads to this I spent half an hour trying to figure out what's wrong with my code but I have no idea, I'm calling this `func` in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func setupNavBarBtn(){
        
        let backBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        backBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cellarrow").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        backBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        backBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        let callBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        callBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Call").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        callBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        callBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn), UIBarButtonItem(customView: callBtn)]

}
```

[image]

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073738/change-size-of-uibarbuttonitem-image-in-swift-3) helps.

Comment: moving the buttons x & y to create some space not working

Comment: Set yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true before assign to frame.

Comment: @RajaKishan I got the same result you are seeing above

Answer (score 1):

You should create UIBarButtonItem instead of UIButton:

```
let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "cellarrow.png"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
let callBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "Call.png"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backBtn,callBtn]
```

The size of bar button should better be 20x20

Comment: it is the Btn Img size that was causing this problem

Comment: I do not know.I think UIButton are not meant to be used in navigation bar. UIBarButton are more likely to manage the correct sizing and behavior.