# Swift: UIBarButtonItem with bigger size than UIToolbar

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a `UIToolbar` installed on my Viewcontroller on the bottom via Storyboard. I also added a bottom in the Storyboard and now I want to give this bottom a greater height than the toolbar itself.

It should be something like that, but it cannot be a Tabbar but needs to be a Toolbar, as the items on it are purely contextual actions and not top level navigation items (see Apple guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/toolbars/)):
[image]

I tried the following code in my Viewcontroller without success (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658154)):

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var ibOutletForButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let menuBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        menuBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 120)
        menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"iconImage"), for: .normal)
        menuBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onMenuButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuBtn)
        let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24)
        currWidth?.isActive = true
        let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 124)
        currHeight?.isActive = true
        ibOutletForButton = menuBarItem
    }
}
```

How could I get the button bigger and moved up that it looks like on the image?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to add the button directly to the `UIViewController` instead of to the `UIToolbar`. You have then complete freedom of positioning and sizing.

As you don't use a `UITabBar`, you will stay within your `UIViewController` and it should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create `4 BarbuttonItem`  after first 2, give some flexible space between items and add your `'plus'` button to toolbar directly in that space.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myToolBar: UIToolbar!
    let menuBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let menuBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        menuBtn.frame = CGRect(x: myToolBar.center.x-10, y: -60, width: 20, height: 120)
        menuBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"iconImage"), for: .normal)
        menuBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onMenuButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
                let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let items = myToolBar.items!
    
        myToolBar.setItems([items[0],items[1],spacer,items[2],items[3]], animated: false)

        myToolBar.addSubview(menuBtn)
      }
```