# Navigation Bar Button Item Alignment Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I'm building a netflix clone. In configuring the nav bar, I keep running into an odd error that I can't seem to find a solution for anywhere: I want my nav bar to contain a "leftBarButtonItem" that houses a UIImage of the Netflix logo w a transparent background (located in my assets folder). But when I attempt to do this, the alignment is always off; as if padding is being added to either side of the image (see screenshots A & B below).

I've tried:

- Replacing the UIImage with a title: String (see screenshots E & F below). Works as expected, but ideally want a UIImage here
- Removing the line containing ".withRenderingMode"
- Swapping out the image in my assets folder for smaller sizes
- Changing the width of the UIImage, unsuccessfully (see screenshots C & D below)

For added context, you can follow the link below to my github repo. The problematic code is in **Controllers > HomeViewController** at line 33

Github Link: https://github.com/nlpope/Netflix-Clone

Failure Screenshots:

[A) When UIImage is included:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llJvC.png)

[B) UIImage result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN9V5.jpg)

[C) When width of -5 is added:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCoxV.png)

[D) altered width result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fc2i.jpg)

Partial-Success Screenshots:

[E) when image is replaced w a title:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c7sF.png)

[F) title result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gExXP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it; The issue was with the size of the netflix logo in the UIBarButtonItem. Before, I was directly assigning the netflix UIImage to **navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem** via the preset **UIBarButtonItem(image:,style:,target:,action:)**,

[netflix clone Mk1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoQuB.png)

instead I should have done this indirctly by passing a **customView** parameter:

[netflix clone Mk2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDIwG.png)

This allowed me to set width and height constraints to the barButtonItem without the custom view (netflix logo) affecting it negatively (because it's just a custom view passed through what we're actually editing

sources: [Change size of UIBarButtonItem (image) in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073738/change-size-of-uibarbuttonitem-image-in-swift-3)